# Laravel phpunit test failing authorization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a working `api` only application.

I am required to write a test  decided to use `laravel`'s phpunit test. This simple app allows only **authenticated** users can `store`, `update` or `delete` a `book`. Everyone else (authenticated or not) can retrieve a list of all `books` or view details of one `book`.

For my `books` test, I have written a test that first creates a `user` then a random `token` for the user. Then the token is passed using `withHeaders` when posting a new book record

```
class BooksTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_onlyAuthenticatedUserCanAddBookSuccessfully()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $token = str_random(10);
        $book = factory(Book::class)->create();

        $response = $this->withHeaders(['Authorization' => "Bearer $token"])
            ->json('POST', '/api/books', [
                'title' => 'book post',
                'author' => 'post author'
            ]);

        $response->assertStatus(201);
    }
}
```

Here I am using the default Laravel 5.6 `UserFactory` and my own `BookFactory`

```
$factory->define(Book::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'     => $faker->sentence,
        'author'    => $faker->name,
        'user_id'   => 1
    ];
});

$factory->define(Rating::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id'   => 1,
        'book_id'   => mt_rand(1, 2),
        'rating'   => mt_rand(1, 5)
    ];
});
```

When I run the test, it fails and I get `401` instead of `200` which means the user is unauthorized.

I have a feeling that I have probably not set the `$user` in my test properly to be used during `POST` but I am not sure and really need help to get it right.

Comment: Hey, the token could not be some random strings, which approch do you use for authenticate users in your api?

Comment: I am using Passport for authentication process. How do I implement authentication in my test then?

Comment: I was using "JWT" before but take a look at this section: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#testing

Comment: @Nevo What does the second argument being the array of scopes that should be granted to the user's token mean? Looking at my code, I don't understand how I will use it during `POST` but using it to create a user is quite straight forward

Comment: The secoend parameter is the scope. I guess if you dont know about it just dont pass secoend argument. and in your code just remove the header from the request and set the passport code just before the request. I guess this will work fine

Comment: Tried using only the first argument which creates a user only and ran the POST test without the headers and got `500` server error response.

Answer (score 1):

you can send headers in the fourth params of json() method  as

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/api/books', [
            'title' => 'book post',
            'author' => 'post author'
        ],['Authorization' => "Bearer $token"]);
```

since json method itself has provision to pass headers

or you can use post() method as

```
 $response = $this->post('/api/books', [
            'title' => 'book post',
            'author' => 'post author'
        ],['Authorization' => "Bearer $token"]);
```

Try this instead hope this solves your issues

Comment: I understand I can send the headers as json() params and can do it too using `withHeaders`, however creating a token like this
`$token = $user->createToken('bookstore')->accessToken;`
and passing it inside the json() params returned this error
`There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\BooksTest::test_onlyAuthenticatedUserCanAddBookSuccessfully
ErrorException: Trying to get property 'client' of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how authentication is hooked on your application, but you could try this:

```php
...

$this->actingAs($user)
    ->jsonPost('/api/books', [
        // ...  
    ]);

$response->assertStatus(201);
```